# Reload before response and uncheck radio button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, radio-button

I am getting response without a refresh! When the user clicks on the button, I want it to reload and then display the response!How can I do that?
And What should I do to uncheck the radio box after the response?

```
<script>
function sendid(attack) {
  var att;
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "battleuser2.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("att=" + attack);

}
</script>
```

This is my radio form:

```
<input type="radio" value="10" id="radioButtonId" onClick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 1
<input type="radio" value="20" id="radioButtonId" onClick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reload and display the response unless you are making the ajax call on page load again.

else you need to store the previous response in localstorage and access it from it when the page reloads again.

Regarding unchecking the radio button after the response, Insert the following code inside the if condition:

```
document.getElementById("radioButtonId").checked = false;
```

example:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("radioButtonId").checked = false;   
    }
```

Comment: can't I use javascript? like location.reload() ? somewhere ?

Comment: You can use it. In that case when the user clicks on the button, you need to call reload() and then when the page loads again, at that time you may need to fire the ajax call.

Comment: To identify that the page is reloaded because of button click, you need to either add some query parameter to URl while reloading else store some flag to localStorage. so when the page reloads you can check that flag and execute the ajax call

Comment: Ok..And you have any idea about, how to uncheck the radio? after the response?

Comment: i have updated answer for that. document.getElementById("radioButtonId").checked = false; insert this inside the if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

Comment: I have updated my post...! the radio form code! 
can you please tell me whether it matches with the uncheck code you provided?